# Managing : (Colon character) in JSON response for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a JSON response from an external service which I want to display in my angular app. A snippet of the JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "entity-type": "documents",
   "pageIndex": 0,
  "pageCount": 1,
  "entries": [
    {
      "entity-type": "document",
      "repository": "default",
      "uid": "5c134e1f-ecbe-4a6a-95f5-e77edb441379",
      "path": "/default-domain/workspaces/AWS",
      "type": "Workspace",
      "state": "project",
      "parentRef": "a0f43384-92b5-4574-957c-16c1804dc410",
      "isCheckedOut": true,
      "changeToken": "1440156904000",
      "title": "AWS",
      "lastModified": "2015-08-21T11:35:04.00Z",
      "properties": {
        "webc:themePerspective": null,
        "webc:useCaptcha": null,
        "dc:description": "All documents relating to Animal Health and Welfare Meetings",
        "dc:language": null,
       "publish:sections": []
      },
      "facets": [
        "Folderish",
        "SuperSpace"
      ]
    },
```

When I want to to reference "dc:description" in the angular app like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><b>Description</b></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">{{workspace.properties.dc:description}}</div>
</div>
```

I get the following console error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 24 of the expression [workspace.properties.dc:description] starting at [:description].
```

I am obviously missing a basic piece of how to handle the : character but I just can't get it.

Thanks
Les

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use square brackets for keys that use special characters.

Try: `workspace.properties['dc:description']` instead.

**Edit**

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors for more details.

To summarize, when using DOT notation:

> [the key] must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

You should use bracket notation in all other cases.